# Using FluentValidation to validate mutually exclusive fields

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm attempting to validate that only one of three fields has a value using FluentValidation.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Date1)
            .Must(x => !x.HasValue)
            .When(x => x.Date2.HasValue || x.Date3.HasValue)
            .WithMessage("Select only one of Date 1, Date 2 and Date 3");
```

This is repeated for the other 2 dates. As would be expected, this produces on message per rule that matches.

There are other rules involved, so is there a way to execute the other rules but fail on the first of these three? I've seen where I could set **CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure** globally but I want the other rules outside of these three to work as they currently do.

Comment: Combine the three rules in a single .Custom(...) rule.

Answer (score 6):

I decide to go down another route. It feels elegant but I'll know if it passes the code review.

I created a new property

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime?> MutuallyExclusiveDates
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<DateTime?>()
            {
                Date1,
                Date2,
                Date3
            };

        }
    }
```

Then I added this rule

```
 RuleFor(x => x.MutuallyExclusiveDates)
            .Must(x => x.Count(d => d.HasValue) <= 1)
            .WithMessage("Select only one of Date 1, Date 2 and Date 3");
```

Comment: Can't you replace the lambda selecting the property value in the RuleFor(...) call with a lambda returning the list containing the three dates? Then you can remove the extra property.

Comment: Yesterday was my first experience using FluentValidation so after trying a few failed methods, this one worked. I like the fact that the model can easily be updated with the dates involved.

Answer (score 4):

Simple one rule for all 3 using xor. No extra properties needed. take out the unless if you want to force at least one to have a value.

```
 RuleFor(x => x).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
     .Must(x => (x.date1.HasValue ^ x.date2.HasValue) ^ x.date3.HasValue)
     .Unless(x => !x.date1.HasValue && !x.date2.HasValue && !x.date3.HasValue)
     .WithMessage("Select only one of Date 1, Date 2 and Date 3");
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like

```
RuleFor(x => x).Must(ValidateDates).WithName("something");

<snip/>

private bool ValidateDates(SomeRequest request)
{
   //perform logic and return true/false;
}
```

Inside the `ValidateDates` method you have access to the full request.

For more examples of complex validation using `Must` take a look at this post -
http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2015/04/complex-model-validation-using-fluent-validation/